# RxScala behave differently in worksheet and after compile

Tags: scala, frp, rx-scala

I was playing around with RxScala and Subject in scala worksheet. But something weird happened.
[image]

as we can see, subscription c also get numbers and output them. After that, I find subscription c is var not val. So, I change the declare. And get following
[image]

This one is correct. So, I copy those code to a main function and run it. It is interesting that the output is same with the second picture whether c is val or not.

Why those happend? Program runing in worksheet is different from those after compiling even with the same code?

Comment: I am using intelliJ in windows and Rxscala is 0.25.0

Comment: For compilation, intellij does some transformations to worksheets, like wrapping in an object and adding lazy to vals. I'm sure that is causing the differences here, but I can't pinpoint exactly what is happening.